# unable to load pdf in browser dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

We are trying to create html to pdf using DOMPDF. When we are saving this to our browser it is created correctly. For creation we are using this function

```
function createPDF($pdf_userid, $pdf_content, $pdf_For, $filename){
$path='dompdf/';
/*$rndNumber=rand();
$filename=$pdf_userid.date("Ymd").$rndNumber.'.pdf';*/
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pdf_content);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($path.$filename, $output);
return $filename;       
}
```

But when we are trying to show pdf in browser without saving on server its showing "Failed to load PDF".
for this we are using this code

```
 try{
    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_content);
    $dompdf->render();
    //$output = $dompdf->output();
    $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
    exit(0);
    }catch(exception $e){
     print_r($e);}
```

Please tell us whats wrong in second code?

Comment: No PHP errors/warnings? Is the PDF error from your reader/browser? You might try opening the PDF in a text editor (e.g. TextEdit or Notepad). Sometimes PHP warnings get caught in the PDF stream.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and download the latest stable version of dompdf from github

```
<?php
    // include autoloader
    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

    // reference the Dompdf namespace
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;

    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);

    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    $context = stream_context_create([ 
        'ssl' => [ 
            'verify_peer' => FALSE, 
            'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
            'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE 
        ] 
    ]);
    $dompdf->setHttpContext($context);

    $html = file_get_contents("html.html");

    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output the generated PDF to browser
    $dompdf->stream();

    // Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
    $dompdf->stream("codexworld",array("Attachment"=>0));
    ?>
```